# Python: first unique number in a list

Tags: python

Just had an interview test where I had to find a first unique (non repeating) element in a list and return it. If no unique elements found, return -1. I was told my solution was not optimal. Can someone suggest a better method?

Here's my code:

```
def solution(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    elif lst == []:
        return -1
    for i in lst:
        if lst.count(i) == 1:
            return i
    return -1
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for [codereview.se].

Comment: What is "non-repeating"?

Comment: I believe in terms of Big O Notation, since the solution presented in O(n^2) whereas an optimal solution would be O(n log n).

Comment: wei2912, got it right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably the most efficient method. It's O(n) since it's just two traversals of the list.

Just fyi, your solution was clearly O(n^2) which is probably why your interviewer didn't like it.

```
# Fast O(n) solution using a dictionary
def solution(lst):
    counts = {}

    for item in lst:
        if item in counts:
            counts[item] += 1
        else:
            counts[item] = 1

    for item in lst:
        if counts[item] == 1:
            return item

    return -1

print(solution([1,2,1,3,2,5])) # prints 3
print(solution([1,2,1,3,3,2,5])) # prints 5
print(solution([1,2,1,3,3,2,5,5])) # prints -1
print(solution([7])) # prints 7
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution; I have a similar one posted above as well, though you got to it first :)

Comment: @wei2912 gave you a +1 as well :)

Comment: You don't need `enumerate`.

Comment: @falsetru Yes true, does `enumerate` slow it down?

Comment: @ShashankGupta, Yes, it does (not so much). But, more importantly, `i` is not used here.

Comment: @falsetru thanks :) I changed the solution to not use `enumerate`. I'm curious to see how well it does vs. yours and Inbar's

Comment: Why use i and range? `for item in lst` reduces the number of times lst is indexed.

Comment: @tdelaney I dont know really, falsetru told me enumerate slows it down. I'm not sure which way is faster but I don't think indexing a list is all that expensive.

Comment: defaultdict would save you a few lines of code.

Comment: I don't mean to use `range` ;)

Comment: @falsetru what would you suggest then?

Comment: `for i in range(len(lst)):` is definitely a code smell. As in this case, it should usually be replaced with `for i in lst:` and the loop body adjusted appropriately.

Answer (score 7):

Using [`collection.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
def solution(it):
    d = OrderedDict()
    for x in it:
        d[x] = d.get(x, 0) + 1
    return next((x for x in d if d[x] == 1), -1)
```

example:

```
>>> solution([1,2,1,3,2,5])
3
>>> solution([1,2,1,3,3,2,5])
5
>>> solution([1,2,1,3,3,2,5,5])
-1
```

**UPDATE**: Alternative solution that use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
def solution(seq):
    d = Counter(seq)
    return next((x for x in seq if d[x] == 1), -1)
```

Comment: @thg435, `Counter` does not guarantee key insertion order. I used `OrderedDict` to get **the first** unique number. Using `Counter`, I have to keep order manually. And I don't want to use original list for iteration.

Comment: I thought about something like `c = Counter(lst); next(x for x in lst if c[x] == 1)`.

Comment: With `OrderedDict` you have the nice feature that `lst` could be something that only iterates once, but I presume you pay for that with a reasonably hefty extra memory use (well, if the list wasn't trivially small).

Comment: @SteveJessop: ah, good point! A note to myself: always use `it` instead of `lst` in SO answers.

Comment: When I time your solution on a simple list [1,2,1,3,2,5] it returns back after 26 seconds on my i7 machine. What could be wrong? Using python 2.7.5

Comment: @casper, How did you time it?

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print (timeit.timeit('solution2([1,2,1,3,2,5])', setup = 'from __main__ import solution2'))`

Comment: formatting is screwed up here, but you get the idea...

Comment: @casper, [`timeit.timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit#timeit.timeit) repeats 1000000 times.

Comment: @thg435, I updated the code to use `it` instead of `lst`. (but not for the second code, because if I pass a iterable to the second one, it will not work as expected.)

Comment: You could also use the [`OrderedCounter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) recipe: `class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict): pass`

Comment: falsetru, second version is still slow - timeit returns:

`[11.147593975067139, 11.195655822753906, 11.045859813690186]`

Comment: @casper, try `print timeit.timeit('solution([1,2,1,3,2,5])', setup='from __main__ import solution', number=1)`

Comment: OK, that is faster, but why is it slowing down when number increases? This does not affect other solutions so much

Comment: On a 1 million elements list with 1 unique at the end:
OrderedDict solution: `[1.8775789737701416, 1.8925399780273438, 1.8907749652862549]`, however Gupta's result: `[0.41011714935302734, 0.39296889305114746, 0.38492703437805176]`

Comment: @casper, Gupta's solution and mine basically have same logic. (with O(n) time complexity). Mine has some overhead, but shorter. Choice is yours.

Answer (score 3):

I will throw my version into the ring:

```
def solution(lst):
    seen = set()
    for i in lst:
        if i in seen:
            continue
        if lst.count(i) == 1:
            return i
        else:
            seen.add(i)
    return -1
```

---

Timers:

```
import timeit
from collections import OrderedDict
test = [1,2,1,3,2,5]

def falsetru(l):
    d = OrderedDict()
    for x in l:
        d[x] = d.get(x, 0) + 1
    return next((x for x in d if d[x] == 1), -1)

def inbar(lst):
    seen = set()
    for i in lst:
        if i in seen:
            continue
        if lst.count(i) == 1:
            return i
        else:
            seen.add(i)
    return -1

>>> print timeit.Timer('inbar(test)', 'from __main__ import *').repeat()
[1.4576762138175334, 1.4347494767197622, 1.4615902215846446]

>>> print timeit.Timer('falsetru(test)', 'from __main__ import *').repeat()
[26.38230001155711, 27.358966390824754, 29.19406918489357]
```

I am surprised by these results.

Comment: How about using `set` instead of `list` for `seen`?

Comment: This could still do a lot more work than is necessary.  Say you have `[1,1,2,2,3,3,...,1000,1000,1001]`.  `lst.count` will have to scan over the whole list 1001 times, when you only need to scan over it once.

Comment: Probably the reason for the surprise is that `falstru` has some significant but linear (or even constant) overhead in `OrderedDict`, whereas `inbar` has a quadratic cost from `lst.count` that is negligible for such a tiny list (6 elements). Try it with 60 million elements, and the first unique one last :-)

Comment: How about `test = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([i]*2 for i in range(1000))) + [1001]` ? ;)

Comment: @falsetru Guys, mind timing my dictionary solution against yours? :) I just added it in an answer here. I'm interested.

Comment: Perhaps I measured incorrectly, with number of measurements limited to 1, falsetru OrderedDict solutions seems be performing much-much faster on long lists.

Answer (score 2):

In the last part of your code:

```
for i in lst:
    if lst.count(i) == 1:
        return i
```

You're iterating through the list in every iteration of your for loop. This results in O(n^2), which is rather slow and not optimal.

I suggest replacing this part with this code:

```
lst.sort()

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if i == 0:
        if lst[i] != lst[i+1]: # if not same as next element
            return lst[i] # okay, it's unique
    if i == len(lst) - 1: # it's the last element
        if lst[i-1] != lst[i]: # let's check if the previous element is the same
            return lst[i] # okay, it's unique
    if lst[i-1] != lst[i] and lst[i] != lst[i+1]: # let's check if the previous element and next element are both not equal to the current element
        return lst[i] # okay, it's unique
```

The sort algorithm finishes in O(n log n) and iterating through the list is O(n), so it's O(n log n).

EDIT: Found that Shashank Gupta had posted before me, so here's another version to consider.

Comment: thanks wei, your solution is a bit slower than Gupta's

Comment: @casper Gupta changed his solution midway, so my edit comment is no longer valid. feel free to pick his, it's a deserving answer (and so are the other answers here) :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about your interview. Next time, impress them with a `numpy` one liner solution:

```
>>> a=array([1,2,1,3,2,5])
>>> a[sum(a==a.T[...,newaxis], axis=1)==1][0]
3
```

OK, not exactly one-liner. You need to use `try` `except` to catch the situation where every element are not unique.

Comment: sorry, I don't know much about numpy, could you elaborate on this solution? what the complete code would look like?